# Why is the compiler complaining about subtracting a negative number?

Tags: c

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
  int a,b;
  a=-3--25;
  b=-3--(-3);
  printf("a=%d b=%d\n",a,b);
  return 0;
 }
```

In this programme, all I think is fine but still while building I got the error that 
[`|5|error: expected ';' before numeric constant|.`] I don't know what is wrong with this programme.

Comment: Look up the ['maximal munch'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch) rule.

Comment: The title to this question is not informative IMHO.

Comment: @user2672165: I trust the rewrite is better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`--` is the decrement operator. You can't apply the decrement operator to numeric constants, because it *changes* what it's applied to. That is

```
--a;
```

*changes* the value of `a`. So `--3` is invalid, you can't change a constant.

If you want to subtract a negative number, you need a space between the minus operator `-` and the negation operator `-`, or `()` around the thing being negated:

```
a = -3 - -25;
b = -3 - -(-3);
```

Separately, note that `-(-3)` is a long-winded way to write `3`.

---

In general, *spaces and blank lines are not the enemy*. Putting spaces around operators, and judicious use of blank lines, generally improves readability.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b;

    a = -3 - -25;
    b = -3 - -(-3);
    printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place some spaces between `-` sign and let the compiler know that you only want to use unary and binary `-`, not decrement operator `--`.

```
a= -3 - -25;
b= -3 - -(-3);
```

Since `--` is decrement operator so `a= -3--25;` is not converted by compiler to `a= -3 - -25;`